Storing mocks in separate file and importing when needed
I'm having a huge problem with Vitest and having to duplicate mocks in every test. I have tried to create a mockable.js file and import them but they are not working as expected and I'm not understanding why.
import { vi } from "vitest";

export default function mockable() {

  const api = () => {
    vi.mock('@/path/to/file.js', () =. ({
      api: () => ({
        something: vi.fn(),
      })
    });
  }

  return {
    api,
  };

}

// test.js

import mockable from "@/mockable.js";

const mock = mockable();

mock.api();
// rest of test

Is there a way this is possible?
